# Why does Lando sound like he's talking over a megaphone, when he hits the radar off the Millennium Falcon?

Tags: star-wars

In *Return Of The Jedi* when Lando Calrissian is flying the Millennium Falcon down the pipeline to the core of the deathstar, he runs into tight space and hits the radar off the ship and Lando quips "That was too close" but when he says it, it sounds like he's speaking over a loud speaker.

Has this ever been addressed directly? And was the sound effect on purpose?

NB: Afaik this sound effect has been there right from original theatrical release to the bluray copies.

Comment: Without checking, I'd guess bad dubbing / overdubbing (poor acoustic match to the original recording environment.)  But if no one has answered this by tomorrow, I'll whip out my copy and watch :)

Comment: Hi Keith did you ever check your copy? its definitely there in the bluray releases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Lando is inside the Death Star we see a shot of him scraping the side of some metal. Then he says "That was too close". His voice has the same echo applied to it as the sound effects in the narrow metal tunnel.  IE: The same echo filter was used on the sound of the Falcon scraping the side and the tie fighters.  If you isolate the sounds before Lando's sentance, you can hear the same echo filter.  You might have to go listen to a tie fighter flying through empty space before you notice that they have the filter applied also.  It might be interesting to do analysis on the echo effect to prove its the same filter as the other noises are filtered by.